Add total of Numbers from Multiple Sheets
I have 2 workbooks. One that one employee will use and one that another will use. On Workbook "A" they are scanning and logging when cars are brought into our garage. THey log the Car Number, The Employee ID and the Time is automatically Logged. This all is ran on a macro that at midnight will create a new sheet to work on. Each sheet is titled Month-Day-Year, IE "Jun-24-24"

I want WorkBook "B" to have a list of each employees Name, correlated to their ID, and how many cars they brought in per day, with a total for each month.
What is the best way to automatically "import"(?) all of the data from Workbook A to Workbook B? Please see below for what Im kinda of imagining Workbook B to look like, with a second sheet for employees total per month.

Thank you very much!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use Power Query in workbook B to import the sheets from workbook A combined into a single query and aggregated as you prefer.
